# Mac and Windows dual boot problem

Tags: mac, windows, hard-drive, bootcamp

I have a software problem with my Mac laptop:
I had made a division in the hard drive some time ago and installed Windows in the other partition using Bootcamp software.
But now I think that the Windows partition is getting full and when I try to switch from Mac to Windows, I get a message saying "inadequate system resources"
and the Windows side does not boot up. Can you tell me what to do to fix this issue?

Thank you very much; I'm stuck and have some important documents on my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Windows partition from Finder (should be possible) to at least save the documents? In Windows, did you try a safe boot (without drivers etc.)?

Comment: If you need to delete NTFS files as part of the resolution, here are some instructions on enabling NFTS read/write: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely to do with the temporary 'swap' files that Windows uses and needs to run. It would be nice to be able to downsize your OS X partition and upsize your Windows partition, but sadly NTFS is not that convenient.

Clear out any unnecessary files from the Windows partition from the Mac side, accessing it through Finder as falconbridge said. Then try and boot into Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to tell you back the crap out of all the files. I had Ubuntu with my Mac OS and because it was 128 GB of solid disk, they both became very full. I tried to get rid of of the Ubuntu by using disk utility and the MAC also got deleted!.

Back to your problem. You need to look at the hard disk format from the disk utility. I think what you did was you tried to alter the partition and the Windows partition got interrupted.

Again, back up everything using Time Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to free up some space by removing some files from the Bootcamp partition within OS X. You should be able to access the Bootcamp drive from the Finder. I recommend trying to free at least 1 GB on the Bootcamp drive and then see if you can boot into Windows.